# Drupal menu link to external site

Tags: drupal

This should be simple but not sure how to fix this.
I have a site (www.mysite.com) with a menu and submenus under it. I want to add new sub menu and when the user clicks on the sub menu title, an external website opens.
So I added the sub menu title, and added the url (https ://www.externalsite.com) to the path and linked it to the main menu. When I enable this and go to click on the it, I get page not found because the url is pointing to https ://www.mysite.com/https://www.externalsite.com

what do I need to do to make it just point to the external site instead of it pointing to an internal page instead?

Comment: What version of drupal are you using? But that shouldn't happen with any. How you see link paths in page source? Did you try switching to default drupal theme and check will that happen again?